# Mongoose create method ignores variable, but not hard coded data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Can someone lead me in the right direction?  I'ven been stuck on this a few days.  I'm using Express and Mongoose.  Here is my controller,

```
module.exports.addPoll = function(req,res) {
  var optionsArray = [];
  var row = [];
  req.body.option1.forEach( function(value) {
    optionsArray.push('{"v":"' + value + '"},{"v":0}');
  });
  var beg = '{"c":[';
  var end = ']}';
  var whole = beg.concat(optionsArray, end);

  Pol.create({
  cols: [{label: "options", type: "string"}, {label: "quantity", type: 
   "number"}],
  rows: whole,
  title: req.body.heading
  }, function(err, poll) {
   if (err) {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 400, err);
   } else {
    sendJSONresponse(res, 201, poll);
    console.log(whole);
  }
});
}
```

When i create the document the rows property is empty.  It ignores the variable that has the data and looks like this.

```
{"__v":0,"rows":{"c":[]},"title":"What is tomorrow","_id":"59826915c7a0186940e8431c","cols":[{"label":"options","type":"string"},{"label":"quantity","type":"number"}]}
```

Here is what it looks like when it logs and if replace the variable withi this, it works perfectly fine.  I don't get it.

```
[{"c":[{"v":"Monday"},{"v":"0"},{"v":"Tuesday"},{"v":"0"}]}]
```

Here is my schema.

```
var rowsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
c: [{
        v: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        _id:false
    },
    {
        v:{
            type:Number,
            required: true
        },
        _id:false
    }],
_id: false
})

var pollSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
cols: [{
        label: {
            type: String, 
            required: true
        }, 
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        _id: false
    },
    {
        label: {
            type: String, 
            required: true
        }, 
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        _id:false
    }],

rows: rowsSchema,

title: {type: String, required:true, _id:false}
})
```

Comment: Because `whole` is a "string" and not an `Object`, and thus is rejected by the "schema". Instead of making a string, simply use an `Object`. i.e `var whole = { c: [].concat.apply([],req.body.options1.map(e => ([{ "v": e },{ "v": 0 }])) }`. Not sure why you want each element to reproduce the `{ "v": 0 }` entry, but that's how you do it.

Comment: That's it.  Thanks.  Don't quite understand how that works but I will make sure I do before I move on.  Thanks again.

Comment: The `[].concat.apply([],..` part is the most difficult to get your head around. But basically put, you are producing an "array of arrays" as the result of `.map()` on the source array input. That part "concatenates" each "array of arrays" entry into a "single array", which is what the content of `"c"` is looking for.